# How can I perform an if/else using the shorthand form within a Bash string?

Tags: bash

Without having to type out another block of `if/else` statements, how can I accomplish this within the string?

I want to avoid having to set the wording based on the boolean. The output from the script takes in `cronjob_status` as a boolean, which in turns does things based on the `true/false` value. I need to perserve the boolean that's being passed in via stdin for `cronjob_status` and I want to print the correct word.

```
if [ "${cronjob_status}" == True ]; then
    cronjob_status_display = "enable"
else
    cronjob_status_display = "disable"
fi



if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Successfully ${cronjob_status_display} the cronjob"
else
    echo "Could not create cronjob" >&2
fi
```

Comment: What command do you have before `if` condition?

Comment: It's an extrnal script I run. `cronjob_status` is being passed as a boolean via stdin. If it's true, I want to print `enable` but if it's false i want to print `disable.` I need the boolean to pass into a different function but the text should print accordingly (not `true` or `false`).

Comment: It is very rarely useful to write conditionals on `$?` (the exception is when different failure codes are used for specific conditions, but even then `if (($? == 2)) ...` is unusual; you'd either save $? In a variable or use a case statement.). If you just want to check if `some_command` succeeded, do that directly: `if some_command some_args; then ... else ... fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
[[ $cronjob_status == True ]] && 
   cronjob_status_display=enable || cronjob_status_display=disable
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to inset all that into one line (within the echo statement). I ended up using your answer and putting it above the echo statement. Works just as well!

Answer (score 2):

Add a short circuit evaluation, `&&`:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "${cronjob_status}" == True ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "NOT OK" >&2
fi
```

---

If you use the `bash` builtin `[[`, then this can also be written as :

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 && ${cronjob_status} == True ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "NOT OK" >&2
fi
```

---

As a side note, you don't necessarily need to check the exit status with `$?`, you can run the command and check at once after that, for example if the command is e.g. `/foo/bar`, you could do:

```
if /foo/bar &>/dev/null && [[ ${cronjob_status} == True ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "NOT OK" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "Successfully ${cronjob_status} the cronjob" || echo "Could not create cronjob" >&2
```